# tshark unwanted print like "Failed to find match"

Tags: logging, tshark

I run following commnad:

tshark -r my_file.pcap -V my_packet > txt_pcap_file.txt

Where:
my_packet is name of same packet
my_file.pcap is file from tcpdump session
txt_pcap_file.txt is file where i want store output of tshark excecution

My problem is that I want to use this command and its output as logs from a larger application and it works fine, but when I run this tshark command I get a lot of printouts like "Failed to find match" and I want to remove them from the console.

Is there anyone who knows how to solve this problem?

I try to change level of logging but it didn't works fine.